# Can't change the size of a MapView [Xamarin]

Tags: ios, xamarin, size, gmsmapview

I have a MapView in my custom ViewRenderer. I am trying to set it's size like this:

```
        public CustomMapRenderer()
        {
            var camera = CameraPosition.FromCamera(47.497913, 19.040236, 15);
           
            mapView = new MapView(new CGRect(0, 0, 414, 200), camera);  //also tried with this: mapView = MapView.FromCamera(new CGRect(0, 0, 414, 200), camera);

            this.AddSubview(mapView);

            ...
         }
```

The view seems to remain in fullscreen though (414*896), if I check it in the debugger though. Since I found not much documentation, I am asking wheter I am setting it correctly? If so, is that a bug? How should I change the size of the view?

**EDIT: Added the relevant XAML code too**

The XAML where the Map is embedded in is:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<attractionbase:AttractionContentListItemBase xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms" 
                 xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
                 xmlns:d="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms/design"
                 xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
                 xmlns:attractionbase="clr-namespace:AppTourism.CardView.ItemTypes.AttractionPage"
                 xmlns:map="clr-namespace:AppTourism.MapModule"
                 mc:Ignorable="d"
                 x:Class="AppTourism.CardView.ItemTypes.AttractionPage.AddressWithMapContentListItem">
        <Frame
            HasShadow="False"
            Padding="0"
            Margin="{Binding MainFrameMargin}"
            RelativeLayout.XConstraint="{ConstraintExpression Type=Constant,Property=X,Constant=0}"
            RelativeLayout.YConstraint="{ConstraintExpression Type=Constant,Property=Y,Constant=0}"
            RelativeLayout.WidthConstraint="{ConstraintExpression Type=RelativeToParent,Property=Width}">
            <StackLayout Orientation="Vertical" Spacing="0" Margin="0" >
                <StackLayout Orientation="Vertical" Margin="10" >
                    <StackLayout Orientation="Horizontal">
                        <Image Source="iMarkerSmall.png" HeightRequest="30"></Image>
                        <Label Text="{Binding Pin.Address}" FontSize="Medium" TextColor="Black"></Label>
                    </StackLayout>
                    <Frame Padding="0" HeightRequest="100" CornerRadius="20" HasShadow="False">
                        <Frame.GestureRecognizers>
                            <TapGestureRecognizer Tapped="Map_Tapped"></TapGestureRecognizer>
                        </Frame.GestureRecognizers>
                        <AbsoluteLayout>
                            <map:CustomMap x:Name="Map" IsEnabled="False"
                                           AbsoluteLayout.LayoutBounds="0,0,1,1" AbsoluteLayout.LayoutFlags="All" />
                            <Label Text="N/A" FontSize="Medium" FontAttributes="Bold" TextColor="Black" Margin="5,0" VerticalOptions="Center" x:Name="NALabel" IsVisible="False"
                                   AbsoluteLayout.LayoutBounds="0.5,0.5,AutoSize,AutoSize" AbsoluteLayout.LayoutFlags="PositionProportional" ></Label>
                        </AbsoluteLayout>
                    </Frame>
                </StackLayout>
                <BoxView HeightRequest="{Binding SEPARATOR_HEIGHT}"  Margin="{Binding SeparatorMargin}">
                    <BoxView.BackgroundColor>
                        <Color>#e6e6e6</Color>
                    </BoxView.BackgroundColor>
                </BoxView>
            </StackLayout>
        </Frame>
    </attractionbase:AttractionContentListItemBase>
```

Comment: You could change the size of MapView in forms directly . By the way , how did you define it in Xaml ? Post the relevant code will behelpful to solve the issue .

Comment: I haven't posted the xaml because it seems irrelevant, since I define the size in the custom ViewRenderer. Changing it didn't seem to change anything related the size of the Map, but I'll add it than.

Comment: This is caused by the parent  layout of the MapView. In your case you should set the size of MapView in forms directly .

Comment: The AboluteLayout? I tried to place the MapView in the StackLayout which contains the Frame, so as a Sibling of the Frame, and tried to set Width/HeightRequest to 100 eg. The inner MapView still has the size fullscreen.

Comment: In AboluteLayout you need to invoked the line `AboluteLayout.SetLayoutBounds(the element, new Rectangle(xx,xx,xx,xx))` instead of setting Width/HeightRequest directly .

Comment: it can be set via XAML isn't it? as it is set now, I only have to set the flags to None, so I can provide exact values right? I tried it that way too though.